# Avoid content duplication after rewriting subdomain to folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have the following rules defined in my `.htaccess`, which I found in another thread a while ago (I do not remember which one):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^((?!sub/).*)$ /sub/$1 [L]
```

The goal is to display any content of `domain.com/sub` as if it were from `sub.domain.com`. This is working properly.

However, there is a small caveat: `sub.domain.com` and `sub.domain.com/sub` are both working.

How can I prevent `sub.domain.com/sub` from being accessible? I tried to rewrite/redirect it to `sub.domain.com` but, of course, I end up with an endless loop redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your first rule as this inside `sub/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove /sub/ from URIs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+sub/(\S*)\s
RewriteRule . /%1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Leave the rule in question in the site root .htaccess.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. For example, I still can access both `sub.domain.com/login.php` and `sub.domain.com/sub/login.php`.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess inside `sub/` folder?

Comment: Yes I do. However, it only contains basic things like the options, mod_deflate, cache-control, etc.

Comment: It's working perfectly and as intended now. Thank you! By the way, I did not _copy_ that rule but I _moved_ it, because I supposed it's useless to have duplicated rules in the `.htaccess` of both the root domain and the sub domain.

Comment: Maybe you can update your answer above telling to separate the 2 rules in 2 files? It may be useful for others who won't read the comments.